# If $X_n$ are independent random variables, then does $\sum_n \mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mathbb{E}(\sum_n X_n)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

If $X_n$ are independent random variables, then does $\sum_n \mathbb{E}(X_n)=\mathbb{E}(\sum_n X_n)$?

This is not a homework problem but rather a question I had. If it is not true, what are the weakest conditions that would make it true? I am aware that if either are absolutely summable, then fubini tells us the answer is yes. I am more interested in the case that fubini does not hold. What weaker conditions can we impose but use the independence of the random variables?

Comment: Indeed, your proposition holds regardless of the dependence of the random variables. For a more general and complete argument you may wanna see the question tagged above.

Comment: I am more interested when the conditions of fubini aren't satisfied. Can the independence give us new weaker conditions?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Why did you see fit to reopen this obvious duplicate?

Comment: @Did I should have red more carefully the revision: it is still a duplicate after this revision.